# Difference between JBoss ESB server and JBoss Fuse

Tags: jboss, esb, jbossfuse, fuseesb

What is the difference between JBoss ESB Server (which is available here:  http://jbossesb.jboss.org/downloads/)

and JBoss Fuse (http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/download/)

How are both functionally different?

Comment: visit this http://blog.vizuri.com/jboss-fuse-vs.-fuse-service-works

Comment: @Clara, thanks for the quick response. the above link has comparision between Fuse & Fuse-service-works. My question was about JBoss ESB and JBoss Fuse

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JBoss ESB is JBoss/RedHats old original ESB product , basically it's old and sooner they will stop the support.

JBoss Fuse is the latest one, RedHat would prefer to sell only this now. It's latest, it uses Apache camel for routing, which is smart and popular one, it uses OSGi which has a different deployment and packaging approach, at last it goes well with RedHats whole other set of offerings and generally it's a technology in trend.

In my terms, JBoss ESB is legacy ;) , JBoss Fuse is preferred and latest for integration solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**JBoss ESB Server :**

The `JBoss ESB Server` is an `application server` that serves as a convenient and lightweight container to deploy to. It is a stripped down version of the JBoss application server that will deploy all of `your WAR, SAR`, but `does not contain EJB3 libraries or deployers`. The `main advantage` of using the `ESB Server` over using the `JBoss ESB 4.12 Server` is that it has a much quicker boot time than the JBoss Application Server, which is helpful during development.

**JBoss Fuse :**

`JBoss Fuse` is an `open source`, lightweight and modular integration platform with a `new-style Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)` that supports `integration beyond the data cente`r. The capability to connect all `enterprise assets and the ability to` `deploy JBoss Fuse` in several different configurations advances intelligent integration to `all facets of your business` – `on premise or in the Cloud`.

JBoss Fuse for `xPaaS extends the integration capabilities` to `OpenShift Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS)` solution.

Comment: Thanks @Clara for the definition. I did not understand the line "integration beyond the data center."  Can you give me an example to clarify.

Comment: The first part (JBoss ESB Server) was copied verbatim from the [JBoss Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossesb/docs/4.9/manuals/html/Getting_Started_Guide/index.html) without attribution (see abstract).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to ask about Fuse ESB and Jboss Fuse. Redhat acquired FuseSource in 2012. It is used for integration using apache camel.

In Jboss Fuse 6+ many new features have come like Fuse Service Works, Fabric etc.
Debugging is lot easier in latest Jboss Developer Studio.

Comment: No I mean JBoss ESB 4.1.2 (mentioned in the downloads page) and JBoss Fuse

Comment: Yes, We use JBoss ESB 4.1.2. It was product of FuseSource now acquired by Redhat and have become Jboss ESB. It is very old version. If you are planning to use something for integration use Jboss Fuse 6+. Meaning of Fuse and ESB is same in terms of integration.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2024, they are transitioning from Red Hat Fuse to the Red Hat build of Apache Camel. But Redhat explicitly doesn't provide anything as ESB, you will have to use multiple solutions from their portfolio of middleware products.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6342381